# python class - function variables scope

Tags: python, oop, scope

I have the following python code:

```
class Geometry_2D:
    def __init__(self, shape_name):
        self.shape_name = shape_name

class Polygon(Geometry_2D):

    def __init__(self, shape_name, verticies_amount):
        Geometry_2D.__init__(self, shape_name)
        self.verticies_amount

    def Adjust_verticies_amount(self):
        self.verticies_amount += 1

triangle = Polygon('triangle', 3)
quadrilateral = triangle.Adjust_verticies_amount()
```

Here I have a variable `verticies_amount` which is defined in `Polygon` class `__init__` function. I need to use `verticies_amount`variable in `Adjust_verticies_amount` function. However, it is not possible, because they are in different scopes. So, my `quadrilateral = triangle.Adjust_verticies_amount()` call won't work.

How should I do it correctly?

Comment: you just forget to declare `self.verticies_amount = verticies_amount`

Comment: You forgot to assign to `self.verticies_amount` in your `Polygon` `__init__`. In the future, saying "it doesn't work" isn't not a sufficient problem specification. Your program would have failed on the following line: `triangle = Polygon('triangle', 3)`, which would give you an `AttributeError`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to set self.vertices_amount in the **init**() method of Polygon

```
class Geometry_2D:
    def __init__(self, shape_name):
        self.shape_name = shape_name

class Polygon(Geometry_2D):
    def __init__(self, shape_name, verticies_amount):
        Geometry_2D.__init__(self, shape_name)
        self.verticies_amount = vertices_amount

    def Adjust_verticies_amount(self):
        self.verticies_amount += 1

triangle = Polygon('triangle', 3)
quadrilateral = triangle.Adjust_verticies_amount()
```